# How to see comments and copyright info on Nikon D3500?

Tags: nikon, dslr, photo-editing, copyright

I've set a comment and copyright info on Nikon D3500, but they aren't visible on the photo and neither is time stamp. Is there any extra setting to make them visible?

Comment: What are you trying to view them with? You mean you want them to actually 'print' into the image, like a 1984 instamatic?

Comment: I want to attach a comment&copyright, but I'm not sure where do I see them. I can't view them "printed" on photos on playback menu, and neither when I export them to my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of comment is added as "metadata" in the image file (typically EXIF). Any decent image viewer can display them (look for "metadata" or "EXIF" or"XMP" in the menus. But it is not printed over the visible image. There are ways to extract the comment from the image file and print it over the image.